# searching all Gmail accounts within the company

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap

Our company uses Google Apps, and I want to find a way to search the All Mail folders of all employees simultaneously: the goal is to return a complete list of emails our company has had to/from a given email address.  I am new to the Gmail APIs - is there a way to do what I'm hoping to do?  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little **worried about the ethics of doing this**, I would imagine it would be a concern for your domain users also but it is technically possible.

I believe this is the kind of service that [Postini](http://www.google.com/postini/) could provide for you.

Alternatively you can use 2 legged OAuth in conjunction with Gmail IMAP.  This could allow you to programmatically iterate through your domain users, login to IMAP and search for the e-mail address. See [Gmail IMAP and SMTP using OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/)

This may sound insecure but in order to enable this behaviour in the first place you would need to have Google Apps adminstrator access to your domain (to enable OAuth access and acquire the domain's *Consumer Secret*).  See also [OAuth: Managing the OAuth key and secret](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=162105)

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  No need to worry about ethics on this one (although I understand why you were) - the employees asked me to figure out how to do this so we could query all the email communications we've had to/from a specific client.  Thanks for the tips - I will check them out - Ron